# Reading custom classes from files in java

Tags: java

In my java class, one thing that we are often asked to do is to read in lines from a file that contain different data types (example `String productName`, `double price`, `int quantity`, etc) and perform tasks with these objects.  So for the example above we'd been working with the class `Product(String productName, double price, int quantity)`.  The only way that I have been able to do this is by storing them all in different `ArrayLists`, which seems very inefficient.  Can anyone provide some insight into a better way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The answer is in the question: use a `List<Product>`.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I read in objects from a file that is formatted like:

Comment: name, price, quantity, each on a new line.  usually, I would want to use a while loop and .hasNextLine, but that would store them all as Strings, right?  I want to read in the first three elements and store them into a new product object

Answer (score 1):

Why not create class `Product` and make it `java.io.Serializable`.
In doing so, you can easily serialize the object to a file as well as de-serialize from a file to the object.